# Manipulating a Python file from C#

Tags: c#, python, parsing, ironpython

I'm working on some tools for a game I'm making. The tools serve as a front end to making editing game files easier. Several of the files are python scripting files. For instance, I have an Items.py file that contains the following (minimalized for example)

```
from ItemModule import *

import copy

class ScriptedItem(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, description, itemtypes, primarytype, flags, usability, value, throwpower):
        Item.__init__(self, name, description, itemtypes, primarytype, flags, usability, value, throwpower, Item.GetNextItemID())
    def Clone(self):
        return copy.deepcopy(self)

ItemLibrary.AddItem(ScriptedItem("Abounding Crystal", "A colourful crystal composed of many smaller crystals. It gives off a warm glow.", ItemType.SynthesisMaterial, ItemType.SynthesisMaterial, 0, ItemUsage.Unusable, 0, 50))
```

As I Mentioned, I want to provide a front end for editing this file without requring an editor to know python/edit the file directly. My editor needs to be able to:

1. Find and list all the class types (in this example, it'd be only
   Scripted Item)
2. Find and list all created items (in this case there'd only be one,
   Abounding Crystal). I'd need to find the type (in this
   caseScriptedItem) and all the parameter values
3. Allow editing of parameters and the creation/removal of items.

To do this, I started writing my own parser, looking for the class keyword and when these recorded classes are use to construct objects. This worked for simple data, but when I started using classes with complex constructors (lists, maps, etc.) it became increasing difficult to correctly parse.

After searching around, I found IronPython made it easy to parse python files, so that's what I went about doing. Once I built the Abstract Syntax Tree I used PythonWalkers to identify and find all the information I need. This works perfectly for reading in data, but I don't see an easy way to push updated data into the Python file. As far as I can tell, there's no way to change the values in the AST and much less so to convert the AST back into a script file. If I'm wrong, I'd love for someone to tell me how I could do this. What I'd need to do now is search through the file until I find the correctly line, then try to push the data into the constructor, ensuring correct ordering.

Is there some obvious solution I'm not seeing? Should I just keeping working on my parser and make it support more complex data types? I really though I had it with the IronPython parser, but I didn't think about how tricky it'd be to push modified data back into the file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You want a source-to-source [program transformation tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).

Such a tool parses a language to an internal data structure (invariably an AST), allows you to modify the AST, and then can regenerate source text from the modified AST without changing essentially anything about the source except where the AST changes were made.

Such a program transformation tool has to parse text to ASTs, and "anti-parse" (called "Prettyprint") ASTs to text.   If IronPython has a prettyprinter, that's what you need.
If it doesn't, you can build one with some (maybe a lot) of effort; as you've observed,
this isn't as easy as one might think.  See my answer
[Compiling an AST back to source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832412/compiling-an-ast-back-to-source-code/5834775#5834775)

If that doesn't work, our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [Python front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/PythonFrontEnd.html) might do the trick.  It has all the above properties.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can find a complete and up-to-date context free grammar file for Python, you could use [CoCo/R](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=coco%20parser&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://ssw.jku.at/coco/&ei=eVmqTuObMOvViALizuXrCg&usg=AFQjCNG-UqYOdP_EkyoQbNt_9X82O1bOIg&sig2=_meMR01ApzT4xIlFzzCYiw) parser generator to generate a python parser in C#.

You can add production code to the grammar file itself to populate a data structure in your C# app. Said data structure can hold all the information you need (methods and their arguments, properties, constructors, destructors etc). Once you have this data structure, its just a task of designing a front end for the user and representing this data structure in a way that makes it editable to them (this is more of a design task than a complicated programming task).

Finally, iterate through you data structure and write out a .py file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python `inspect` module to print the source of an object. In your case: To print the source of your module - the file you just parsed with IronPython. I haven't checked to see if inspect works with IronPython yet, though.

As to adding stuff, well, it's a module, right? You can just add stuff to a module... I'd load the module and then alter it, use `inspect` to view print it and save to disk.

From your post, it looks like you're already deep in the trenches and having fun, so I'd be really happy to see a post here on how you solved this problem!

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds more like you are at the point where you shove it all into a sqlite database and start editing it that way.  Hooking up some forms to edit tables is simpler for the UI.  At that point you generate new python files by dumping your tables out with some formatting to provide the surrounding python scripts.

SVN / Git / whatever can merge the updated changes via the python files.

This is what I ended up doing for my project at any rate.  I started using python to hook up the various items using their computed keys and then just added some forms UI to avoid editing mistakes in the python files.