# Is there an established way to write parsers that can reconstruct their exact input?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, bijection

Say I want to parse a file in language *X*. Really, I'm only interested in a small part of the information within. It's easy enough to write a parser in one of Haskell's many eDSLs for that purpose (e.g. Megaparsec).

```
data Foo = Foo Int  -- the information I'm after.

parseFoo :: Parsec Text Foo
parseFoo = ...
```

That readily gives rise to a function `getFoo :: Text -> Maybe Foo`.

But now I would also like to *modify* the source of the `Foo` information, i.e. basically I want to implement

```
changeFoo :: (Foo -> Foo) -> Text -> Text
```

with the properties

```
changeFoo id ≡ id
getFoo . changeFoo f ≡ fmap f . getFoo
```

It's possible to do that by changing the result of the parser to something like a lens

```
parseFoo :: Parsec Text (Foo, Foo -> Text)
parseFoo = ...
```

but that makes the definition a lot more cumbersome – I can't just gloss over irrelevant information anymore, but need to store the match of every `string` subparse and manually reassemble it.

This could be somewhat automated by keeping the string-reassembage in a `StateT` layer around the parser monad, but I couldn't just use the existing primitive parsers.

Is there an existing solution for this problem?

Comment: Parsing libraries generally construct an "Abstract Syntax Tree", which leaves out all formatting. What you are looking for is a "Concrete Syntax Tree". I don't know of any libraries which build this.

Comment: I usually use [definite clause grammars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44347314/975097) in Prolog for bidirectional parsing, but I haven't seen anything like this in Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a case of "bidirectional transformation"? E.g.,  http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1571/

In particular, "Invertible Syntax Descriptions: Unifying Parsing and Pretty Printing" by Rendel and Osterman 
http://dblp.org/rec/conf/haskell/RendelO10 , Haskell Symposium 2010 (cf. http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4191 )

Comment: Yes, that's great work; but does it really adress my problem? I was under the impression that these invertible parsers mainly guarantee `parse . print ≡ id`. Can they also assure anything about `print . parse`?

Comment: If you're pretty-printing, then `print ( parse s) === s` modulo whitespace? It should be even easier to build basic printer/parsers for exact-printing.

Comment: Well, the thing is, in my application _most_ of the file is “whitespace” (or rather “comments”), since I don't bother to actually parse most of the content in detail, only a few variables.

Comment: You need a whitespace parser that returns what it has read, and not ignores it? The "lens" model looks reasonable to me. Whether it's useful would depend on the combinators. I would not just blame the type...

Answer (score 1):

A solution implemented in Haskell?  I don't know of one; they may exist.

In general, though, one can store enough information to regenerate a legal version of the program that resembles the original to an arbitrary degree, by storing "formatting" information with collected tokens.  In the limit, the format information *is* the original string for the token; any approximation of that will give successively less accurate answers.

If you keep whitespace as explicit tokens in the parse tree, in the limit you can even regenerate that.   Whether that is useful likely depends on the application.  In general, I think this is overkill.

Details on what/how to capture and how to regenerate can be found in my SO answer: [Compiling an AST back to source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832412/compiling-an-ast-back-to-source-code/5834775#5834775)