# In antlr, is there a way to get parsed text of a CommonTree in AST mode?

Tags: java, antlr

A simple example:

```
(grammar):

stat: ID '=' expr NEWLINE -> ^('=' ID expr)

expr: atom '+' atom -> ^(+ atom atom)

atom: INT | ID

...

(input text): a = 3 + 5
```

The corresponding CommonTree for '3 + 5' contains a '+' token and two children (3, 5).

At this point, what is the best way to recover the original input text that parsed into this tree ('3 + 5')?

I've got the text, position and the line number of individual tokens in the `CommonTree` object, so theoretically it's possible to make sure only white space tokens are discarded and piece them together using this information, but it looks error prone.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: To do this for real languages is complicated.  See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5834775/120163.  The same principles apply to ANTLR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Better, I don't know. There *is* another way, of course. You decide what's better.

Another option would be to create a custom AST node class (and corresponding node-adapter) and add the matched text to this AST node during parsing. The trick here is to not use `skip()`, which discards the token from the lexer, but to put it on the `HIDDEN` channel. This is effectively the same, however, the text these (hidden) tokens match are still available in the parser.

A quick demo: put all these 3 file in a directory named `demo`:

### demo/T.g

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=XTree;
}

@parser::header {
  package demo;
  import demo.*;
}

@lexer::header {
  package demo;
  import demo.*;
}

parse
 : expr EOF -> expr
 ;

expr
@after{$expr.tree.matched = $expr.text;}
 : Int '+' Int ';' -> ^('+' Int Int)
 ;

Int
 : '0'..'9'+
 ;

Space
 : ' ' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
 ;
```

### demo/XTree.java

```
package demo;

import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;

public class XTree extends CommonTree {

  protected String matched;

  public XTree(Token t) {
    super(t);
    matched = null;
  }
}
```

### demo/Main.java

```
package demo;

import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = "12    +  42 ;";
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.setTreeAdaptor(new CommonTreeAdaptor(){
      @Override
      public Object create(Token t) {
        return new XTree(t);
      }
    }); 
    XTree root = (XTree)parser.parse().getTree();
    System.out.println("tree    : " + root.toStringTree());
    System.out.println("matched : " + root.matched);    
  }
}
```

You can run this demo by opening a shell and cd-ing to the directory that holds the `demo` directory and execute the following:

```
java -cp demo/antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool demo/T.g
javac -cp demo/antlr-3.3.jar demo/*.java
java -cp .:demo/antlr-3.3.jar demo.Main
```

which will produce the following output:

```
tree    : (+ 12 42)
matched : 12    +  42 ;
```

Comment: Ah, that is a lot better. :-) I did not know you could get to the text with $expr.text after parsing. In my case, I do not care about the white spaces, but it's nice to know you can get them in the parser if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `TokenRewriteStream` which has several `toString()` methods.

To borrow from @Bart Kiers' example [Demo/Main.java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942825/22876)

```
TokenRewriteStream tokens = new TokenRewriteStream(lexer)
TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);
...
tokens.toString(n.getTokenStartIndex(), n.getTokenStopIndex() + 1).trim()
```

So given any node 'n' of your parse tree, calling toString() on it as above will produce the string that "generated" this node.