# Generate Java Source Code for Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I had generated AST of java grammer using Antlr.

I had made some alterations in the AST, Now I need to write the AST as Java File at a particular location.

Could any one suggest me the available ways to do the same.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: To generate a String of Java code from the AST you should be able to just traverse the tree and output each node's content in the right order. Writing the data to a file is straight forward then.

Answer (score 1):

There's more to this than "walk the tree and spit text". See [this SO answer for how to do prettyprinting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834775/120163)

ANTLR has so-called "string templates" which are likely to be of some help here.