# How to generate JavaScript code from AST in SpiderMonkey?

Tags: javascript, parsing, mozilla, spidermonkey

I am using [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API) for a project and I need it for 2 tasks:

1. Getting AST node information given a JavaScript string.
2. Writing JavaScript from an AST node.

The first task is accomplished by means of `js Reflect.parse('var a = 13;');` which returns me the AST, fine!

### From AST to JavaScript

The second task is what I need. I want to instruct `js` (or probably the `Reflect` object, I suppose) to take a node:

```
{
  type:"Program", 
  body:[
    {
      type:"VariableDeclaration", 
      kind:"var", 
      declarations:[
        {
          type:"VariableDeclarator", 
          id:{type:"Identifier", name:"a"}, 
          init:{type:"Literal", value:13}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And write down: `var a = 13;`.

How can I achieve this which is sort of a reverse process to `Reflect.parse`? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If Spidermonkey hasn't got a built-in module to do this, you'll have to build one yourself.

All the details you need to do that are here: [Compiling an AST back to source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832412/compiling-an-ast-back-to-source-code/5834775#5834775)