# How do I deparse a Clang translation unit to C++?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I have an AST that has been parsed by Clang. How do I generate the equivalent C++ code for the AST? I would like the result as an `std::string` and formatted in a readable way.

Another way of putting this question is: can I use clang-format like a library?

For example, the AST of this source code:

```
 int  main()  {

         int   y  = 4;
       int  x =  y+ 7;  return  0;}
```

... might become this `std::string`:

```
int main()
{
    int y = 4;
    int x = y + 7;
    return 0;
}
```

The ideal API would be something like:

```
std::string deparse(clang::TranslationUnitDecl* root)
```

Comment: #includes are always processed before LLVM gets code, so you will actually get the preprocessed file, which includes the contents of iostream (and whatever headers it itself includes)

Comment: @PaulStelian That's OK; I would like to see the preprocessed code.

Comment: @PaulStelian But isn't clang-format able to handle includes? I am working at a Clang level, before any LLVM is generated.

Comment: Not for Clang, but a similar tool, our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit, provides exactly fully scriptable parsing and unparsing capability for many languages, including C++. (It can even retain almost all preprocessor directives).  I'll note that regenerating source code from an AST is harder than it looks: see my SO answer on how to build a prtettyprinter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832412/compiling-an-ast-back-to-source-code/5834775#5834775

Comment: @sdgfsdh The thing is that Clang gets the already preprocessed files, where includes and preprocessor directives (except Pragma) have already been processed and are no longer present.