# Converting string typed Abstract Syntax Tree(AST) to Python Code?

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on a parsed AST string of Python code. Now, I am at a stage where I want to convert small tree structures back to code for some analysis.

```
import ast
ast_string = ast.dump(ast.parse("[1,2,3]"))
print(ast_string)
# 'Module(body=[Expr(value=List(elts=[Num(n=1), Num(n=2), Num(n=3)], ctx=Load()))])'
```

Now, I want to convert this `Module(body=[Expr(value=List(elts=[Num(n=1), Num(n=2), Num(n=3)], ctx=Load()))])` back to code.

Example:

```
def ast_to_code(ast_string):
   ....

code = ast_to_code(ast_string)
print(code) # [1,2,3]
```

Thanks in advance. I have searched over the web found different libraries that take a parse tree object and then convert it back to code. I wasn't able to find something that can convert any AST tree in string back to code.

Comment: See my answer on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834775/120163

Comment: Nomiluks: I have this identical problem, did you find any Python solutions?

Comment: have your tried libcst? I am able to generate code from node here's also the post related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771691/python-libcst-unable-to-generate-code-from-the-node-in-visitor-class

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways by which the AST string can be converted back to an `ast.AST`. The first solution is the shortest, since it involves substituting `ast.AST` subclass names in the original string with their module dot lookup, and then using `eval` to produce a result:

```
import ast, re
def ast_to_code(ast_string):
   return ast.unparse(eval(re.sub('\w+(?=\()', lambda x:f'ast.{x.group()}', ast_string)))

ast_string = ast.dump(ast.parse("[1,2,3]"))
print(ast_to_code(ast_string))
#even shorter option with star import:
from ast import *
print(ast.unparse(eval(ast.dump(ast.parse("[1,2,3]")))))
```

Output:

```
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

Of course, the solution above is a bit hackish and rather insecure due to the use of `eval`. An alternative is to parse the AST string (itself valid Python syntax) to an `ast` object, then traverse the result and create a new `ast` object:

```
import ast
ast_string = ast.dump(ast.parse("[1,2,3]"))
def to_ast(d):
   if isinstance(d, ast.Call):
      return getattr(ast, d.func.id)(*map(to_ast, d.args), 
                     **{i.arg:to_ast(i.value) for i in d.keywords}, **{'lineno': None, 'col_offset': None, 'end_lineno': None, 'end_col_offset': None})
   if isinstance(d, ast.List):
      return list(map(to_ast, d.elts))
   return d.value

def ast_to_code(ast_string):
   return ast.unparse(to_ast(ast.parse(ast_string).body[0].value))

print(ast_to_code(ast_string))
```

Output:

```
'[1, 2, 3]'
```